# sql case statement in where clause in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

Here is my string sql query, but i am unable to convert it to linq as it contains cases based where clause, any help will be appreciated.

```
if (StrClientID.Equals("008"))
                   objdbhims.Query += "   and (( case when t.external_org is null then d.clientid='008' end) or t.external_org in ('008','-1'))";
               else if (StrClientID.Equals("006"))
                   objdbhims.Query += " and (t.external_org<>'008' or (case when t.external_org is null then d.clientid='" + StrClientID + "' end))";
               else
                   objdbhims.Query += " and d.clientid='"+StrClientID+"'";
```

Comment: you can use ternary operator `<test> ? <valueiftrue> : <valueiffalse>` in linq

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus case statement replace is if else but in ternary operator when i do <test> ? <valueiftrue> and i dont put else part it gives syntax error, i don't want else part, how to do that/

Comment: well you can just put something like `m => true` in the second part then...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus thanks you advise worked as charm...:)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it myself after struggling alot with this solution by using ternary operator, i just put 1==1 in the else part to get rid of error:

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"008","-1"};

string ClientID = HttpContext.Current.Session["ClientID"].ToString();

&& (
                                ClientID == "008"
                             ? (t.external_org == null 
                                               ? d.clientid =="008" : 1 == 1)
                                               || (arr.Contains(t.external_org))


                                : ClientID == "006"
                             ? (t.external_org == null
                                               ? d.clientid == ClientID : 1 == 1)
                                               || (t.external_org != "008")

                        : d.clientid == ClientID
                            )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may add a lot of Where clauses to your IQueryable object before fetching data from DB. For example:

```
var data = SomeContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.SomeField == someValue);
if (someCondition) 
{
  // Something like your 1st if clause
  data = data.Where(x => (x.SomeField2 != null && x.SomeField3 == "someText") || new[] { "001", "002" }.Contains(x.SomeField2));
}

var result = data.ToList();
```

Comment: how to do this part?....case when t.external_org is null then d.clientid='008' end) or t.external_org in ('008','-1'))"

Comment: it is check against table column value and on base of that i am adding where d.clientid ="008"

Comment: It depends from your relation between t and d tables in Linq. If, for example, d is Client, and t has the property of type Client, then you may write t.Client.clientid == "008". If t has a list of Client(s) and you want to get all t records, where t.Clients has some client with specific id, you may write this - t.Clients.Any(y => y.clientid == "008")